# Rails Tutorial 11.1 - ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, railstutorial.org

So I've been working my way through the Hartl Rails Tutorial and I'm encountering an error for the section where we follow other users. Given that I'm doing the Tutorial you know I'm relatively noobish, but I can't figure out the problem. As far as I can tell am appropriately using the has_many through relationship and am explicit with the source and foreign key, but am evidently missing something. I cannot decipher what the error means when it says `Is it one of :follower or :followed?`

The failing tests are:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end
.
.
.
    describe "following" do
    let(:other_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    before do
      @user.save
      @user.follow!(other_user)
    end

    it {should be_following(other_user)}
    ***its(:followed_users) {should include(other_user)}

    describe "followed user" do
      subject {other_user}
      its(:followers) {should include(@user)}
    end

    describe "and unfollowing" do
      before {@user.unfollow!(other_user)}

      it {should_not be_following(other_user)}
      ***its(:followed_users) {should_not include(other_user)}
    end
  end
end
```

The error I get is:

```
 Failure/Error: its(:followed_users) {should include(other_user)}
 ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError:
   Could not find the source association(s) :followed_id in model Relationship. Try 'has_many :followed_users, :through => :relationships, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :follower or :followed?
```

My models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  ***has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: "followed_id"
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name: "Relationship", dependent: :destroy

  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower
.
.
.
  def feed
    #this is preliminary 
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end

  private
    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

And my schema:

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :relationships, :follower_id
    add_index :relationships, :followed_id
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Thanks for reading! If I left out anything important I will be sure to edit, but I think I hit everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
```

The is because `source` wants the name of the association that the records are loaded from (not the foreign key)

Comment: Derp how did I not notice that the opposite relationship had the correct notation... Thanks a bunch!